# Python Function to Compute Total Cost in Linear Regression

Tags: python

I have a Python function that computes the total cost for a linear regression model. The function takes the weights (w), bias (b), input data (X), and labels (y) as inputs. It is expected to iterate over the training examples, calculate the prediction for each example, and then compute the cost for that example using the mean squared error formula.

Here's the formula for the prediction:
(()) = () +

And the formula for the cost:
() = ((()) - ()) ^ 2

The total cost over all examples is then computed as follows:
(,) = 1/2 * ∑=0−1 ()

However, it seems there might be some issues in the implementation as it's not returning the correct cost. Could someone please help me review the function and identify any mistakes or improvements needed to correctly compute the total cost over all examples in the linear regression model?

What I tried:
I implemented the compute_cost function, as described in the original prompt, in Python.

What I expected to happen:
The function is expected to compute the total cost over all training examples in a linear regression model. It should iterate over the training examples, calculate the prediction for each example using the given weights (w) and bias (b), and then compute the cost for that example using the mean squared error formula. Finally, it should return the total cost.

What actually resulted:
The implementation appears to be correct in terms of the mathematical formulas provided in the prompt. However, there might be some issues with the code that could potentially lead to incorrect results. For instance, the code doesn't import the necessary libraries (numpy) and is missing an import statement for that. Additionally, if there are issues with the input data or the data shapes, the function may not work as expected.

import numpy as np

def compute_cost(w, b, X, y):
"""
Compute the cost for a linear regression model.

```
Arguments:
w -- weights, a numpy array of size (num_features, 1)
b -- bias, a scalar
X -- input data, a numpy array of size (num_examples, num_features)
y -- labels, a numpy array of size (num_examples, 1)

Returns:
cost -- total cost over all examples, a scalar
"""

m = X.shape[0]  # number of training examples
cost = 0


for i in range(m):
    # Compute the prediction of the model for the i-th example
    f_w_b = np.dot(X[i], w) + b
    
    
    cost_i = 0.5 * (f_w_b - y[i]) ** 2
    
  
    cost += cost_i


cost /= m

return cost
```

X = np.array([[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]])  # Features (5 training examples)
y = np.array([[2], [4], [6], [8], [10]])  # Labels

weights = np.array([[2]])  # Single feature, single weight
bias = 0

total_cost = compute_cost(weights, bias, X, y)

print("Total cost:", total_cost)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please leave an example of the code that you tried so that I (or others) can help you out. Also, have you tried looking for similar questions already?